# Distinct user can process unique data associated with them, then how to add this specific data to a specific user for load testing in Jmeter

Tags: csv, set, jmeter

One Login can use data from his jurisdiction only. For load testing with Jmeter how can we create CSV File which has unique data for  unique Login .

Answer (score 0):

You can create users in format:

1. User1
2. User2

   .. User100

Then if you do a load with 100 threads, you can simply add ${__threadNum} and every single thread will have a different user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data you need you can create a csv with the fields username,password,data1,data2...etc.

Then user a CSV data set config in the variable names put:

```
USER_NAME,PASS,DATA_1,DATA_2
```

Be sure there are no spaces between your variable names

You can then call these  variables as ${USER_NAME}, ${PASS}, ${DATA_1}, and ${DATA_2}.  Each thread will use the values from a different row in the csv, i.e. thread1 will use row1, thread2 will use  row2, etc.